# If $x$ is a $p$-value, what do we call $x\cdot (1-x)$?

Tags: terminology, statistics, functions

What do you call this function?

$$f(x) = x(1 - x)$$

Does it have a name?  It’s cropped up in at least two statistical formulas I've been asked to program so far.  (In both cases, $x$ was something called a *$p$-value* (for what it's worth).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `Z` can take values 1 or 0 with probability `x` and `1-x`, respectively, we usually call `x*(1-x)` the **variance** of Z.

This is a special case of the more general [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition) formula, and works because Z is what we call an [indicator variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function#Mean.2C_Variance_and_covariance).